# how to jump to next dropdown after a value change?

Tags: javascript, html, select, onchange, onkeydown

Let's say I have about 20 Dropdowns in a row and want automatically jump to the next one after changing the value with the keyboard. How to do this?
I found out that the onchange event only fires when the dropdowns loses the focus (like onblur). So I tried onkeydown instead but this seems very unstable and buggy.

This is what I tried:

```
<script>
function keydown(dd, e) {
    console.log(dd.value)
    jumptonext(dd);
}
function getNext(current) {
    var all = document.querySelectorAll('select[onkeydown]');
    for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
        if (all[i] == current && all[i+1]) return all[i+1];
    }
    return all[0];
}
function jumptonext(current) {
    var next = getNext(current);
    next.focus();
}
</script>
<select onkeydown="keydown(this, event)">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select onkeydown="keydown(this, event)">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select onkeydown="keydown(this, event)">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select onkeydown="keydown(this, event)">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

But as you can see in the console log the values are incorrect.

Is there a way to change the value of the dropdown with the keyboard **and then** jump to the next dropdown and do the same?

Comment: Why would you want this? If I'm using the keyboard, then I don't want it to jump when I switch like that, because I could be using arrow down to switch between options. When I'm done, I'll press [Tab] to go to the next option.

Comment: Because my boss wants it exactly like that. I'm not very happy with this decision but he wants it so I have to do it - somehow.

Comment: Well, try explaining to him the lack of functionality. If not, did you try keyup?

Answer (score 0):

set some interval function which checks the current values of all selects e.g. with a period 10ms. If the value of one of them has been changed - see what was it and move the focus to the next select.

```
// define array of current values
var values = new Array();

// here fill it with values of your selects

setInterval(function(){
  // here check if some value was changed
  // if there is one changed
    // set the new value into array as a current one
    // jump to next select with .focus()
},10);
```

I think this should be enough for your boss.

Maybe you will also need to .blur() the current one (just a guess).

Sorry, but seems it is the only ugly way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

you can handle it via jquery.

i'm using it for "tab" press.

```
$('body').on('keydown', 'input, select, textarea', function(e) {
var self = $(this)
  , form = self.parents('form:eq(0)')
  , focusable
  , next
  ;

$('.dropBpx').change(function(){

    focusable = form.find('input,a,select,button,textarea').filter(':visible');
    next = focusable.eq(focusable.index(this)+1);
    if (next.length) {
        next.focus();
    } else {
        form.submit();
    }
    return false;

});
```

});

i think it's ok with this code buy you need to make some changes.